# Woocommerce fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to build a plugin and i am stack on this weird fatal error when i think it shouldn't be there.

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_plugin' );
function my_custom_plugin() {   
  global $product;
  if (is_product()) {
    $product_type = $product->get_type();
    if ($product_type =='variable') { 
        ...things happening here....
    }
  }
}
```

I have also this code included in my file `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`

thank you :)

Comment: Right under `global $product;`, can you do `print_r($product);` and tell me if any data returns?

Comment: test-a  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type()
test-a is the slug of the product

Comment: still only this info : test-a . And then the product. So it gives the product but when i call it in my function is empty :/

Comment: do you think that it fires very early in the code because it runs on `wp_head`? I am very confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's happening, but you could try this code to see if it works for you or not. It works on my end:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_plugin' );

function my_custom_plugin() 
{   
  global $post;

  if (is_product()) {
    $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
    $product_type = $product->get_type();
    if($product_type == 'variable'){ 
    // ...things happening here....
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: yup that did the job thank you very much. isn't it somehow weird that $product won't load?

Comment: @GiannisMargetis That's because the `wp_head` hook is executed on every front end page, including pages where `$product` is not available, like for example blog pages. 
`is_product()` returns true when viewing a single product page, so if you put `global $product` after that if condition it will work, because `$product` 
will be available on the single product page

Comment: Interesting! Good to know, thanks @7uc1f3r for your explanation.

Comment: thank you @7uc1f3r ill try it and share the findings.